# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired on commit

Tags: sql-server, transactions, timeout, bigdata

I am writing some code that is importing a large amount of data into three tables currently around 6 million rows across the three tables. I am wanting to do this in a transaction so if there are any issues or the user cancels the import nothing is imported. This works fine on my own development machine however on a slower amazon ec2 instance and micro sql instance I am getting the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding
```

Now I know that the commit is finishing eventually because the data is present in the tables when I look, so my question is; can this be easily avoided without adding the connection timeout property to my connection string (I only want this one operation to not timeout) or is this a really hard/dangerous thing to be doing?
I am not sure if maybe I should import into holding tables and then call stored procedures to move the data when I am ready because I would assume this will result in a shorter transaction)

I am using Ms Sql server 2012.
Do comment if I need to add more data.
Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Check what is the SP getting timedout .. if you have any third party tool like Redgate or Avicode you can figure it out ..or use Profiler to figure it out.. then see the execution plan for the SP or query .. If you find any Key lookups or RID lookups then resolve it first and try again..

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying here, the stored procedures and queries to actually get the data into the tables are not timing out and the above exception is being thrown when I call the commit method in the transaction object.